# Draw bar charts with rounded rectangles in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to add rounded rectangles to a bar chart I've created in dc.js. I've tried adding a renderlet, but that didn't work. Then tried to add this bit of code after the dc.renderAll() call:

```
dc.transition(svg.selectAll('rect'), chartProjectsCreatedChart.transitionDuration())
            .attr('rx', 5)
            .attr('ry', 5)
```

Interestingly, this gives a rounded rectangle to the legend but not the individual chart bars

[image]

, even though the elements all have "rx" and "ry" attributes.

[image]

I see that dc.heatmap has xBorderRadius and yBorderRadius attributes, but they don't seem to be there for normal barcharts.

Thanks

Comment: OK. So, this can be changed in the css but has to specifically target `rect.bar`

Comment: It works when I apply it directly to [the basic bar chart example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar.html). However, it cancelled the original transitions when I applied it with a transition (not sure why you'd want to do that), so I had to apply the attributes directly, like `chart.selectAll('rect').attr('rx', 5).attr('ry', 5);` Not sure if that was part of your problem. It also would make more sense to apply it in a renderlet or pretransition event so that it applies to any new bars added later. Or yeah, CSS is probably better!

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Off-topic slightly, but could you possibly point me in the direction of a good resource for the renderlet functionality - at the moment, I'm simply hacking my way through them with an astonished look on my face whenever it succeeds.

Comment: Sure. It's just an event; you may find old examples around the Web where it was another mechanism. [Docs](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinon--basemixin) ; [example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/examples/bar-extra-line.html)

Answer (score 1):

**D3.js V5 + DC.js Solution**

```
chart.on('pretransition', (chart) => {
      const svg = chart.select('svg');

      // Bar Border Radius
      svg.selectAll("rect")
          .attr("rx", "5")
          .attr("ry", "5");
});
```